# Jersey Client Error - Unable to Parse Invalid Content-Type Header (need workaround)

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I'm using Jersey Client `2.29` I believe.
When handling a request the server responds with `Content-Type = application/` (of course that is a bogus value it is supposed to be `application/json`).  `jersey` blows up because it can't parse the subtype of the media type:

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.HeaderValueException: Unable to parse "Content-Type" header value: "application/"
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.HeaderValueException: Unable to parse "Content-Type" header value: "application/"
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.exception(InboundMessageContext.java:314)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.singleHeader(InboundMessageContext.java:309)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.getMediaType(InboundMessageContext.java:422)
    at com.test.web.ext.filter.LoggingFilter.filter(LoggingFilter.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientFilteringStages$ResponseFilterStage.apply(ClientFilteringStages.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientFilteringStages$ResponseFilterStage.apply(ClientFilteringStages.java:97)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:147)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$invoke$1(JerseyInvocation.java:743)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:390)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:741)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:432)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyCompletionStageRxInvoker.lambda$method$1(JerseyCompletionStageRxInvoker.java:46)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error parsing media type 'application/'
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext$5.apply(InboundMessageContext.java:428)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext$5.apply(InboundMessageContext.java:422)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.singleHeader(InboundMessageContext.java:307)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error parsing media type 'application/'
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MediaTypeProvider.fromString(MediaTypeProvider.java:69)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MediaTypeProvider.fromString(MediaTypeProvider.java:37)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:196)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext$5.apply(InboundMessageContext.java:426)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: End of header.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.HttpHeaderReaderImpl.getNextCharacter(HttpHeaderReaderImpl.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.HttpHeaderReaderImpl.next(HttpHeaderReaderImpl.java:116)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.HttpHeaderReaderImpl.next(HttpHeaderReaderImpl.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.HttpHeaderReader.nextToken(HttpHeaderReader.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MediaTypeProvider.valueOf(MediaTypeProvider.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MediaTypeProvider.fromString(MediaTypeProvider.java:67)
    ... 23 more
```

[github-MediaTypeProvider](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/MediaTypeProvider.java#L90)
I have no control of this 3rd party server and I have to be able to process this request.
Is there anyway around this?
Some property, setting, registering a custom media type provider, anything?

P.S.
I have successfully used `ByteBuddy` to redefine this method at runtime and handle the error with some extra special sauce but that is a major hack... I'd love a better option if it exists.

**Client Configuration**

```
final Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
  .property(ClientProperties.REQUEST_ENTITY_PROCESSING, RequestEntityProcessing.CHUNKED)
  .property(ClientProperties.FOLLOW_REDIRECTS, false)
  .sslContext(tls)
  .hostnameVerifier(new NoOpHostnameVerifier())
  .register(new CookiePersistFilter(NARRATIVE)) // @Priority(HEADER_DECORATOR)
  .register(new LoggingFilter(NARRATIVE))       // @Priority(USER)
  .register(MyFilter.class)                     // @Priority(50000)
  .register(JsonReader.class)
  .register(JsonWriter.class)
  .register(HTMLReader.class)
  .register(MultiPartFeature.class)
  .build();
```

Filters are executed in this order:

1. MyFilter
2. LoggingFilter
3. CookiePersistFilter

Comment: Since this error doesn't occur until you call `readEntity()`, I think you can just manually set the response header before calling `readEntity()`. Like `response.getHeaders().putSingle("Content-Type", "application/json")`

Comment: Hi @PaulSamsotha, thanks for the idea.  I have updated the stacktrace that shows this happening in a filter too.  So I think I need to handle this before I read the entity or it goes through any other filters to be safe.  Can I use a response filter?  If so how do I prioritize it first?  I tried annotating with @Rank(1) but it doesn't seem to have any affect on ordering (it calls my other filter first, ranked Priorities.USER which blows up).

Comment: The correct way to use priorities is with `@Priority` or when you call `register()` -- use the overload that let's you specify a number priority.

Comment: My fault @PaulSamsotha, I was confusing Rank and Priority.  So I tried the priority and it worked.  However, the ordering is not what I expected. For my jersey client, it seems to sort descending (highest number, highest priority), when the priorities docs state the opposite.  Is this expected?

Comment: I added my client config with filter ordering above just in case.

Comment: [Providers used during response processing (ContainerResponseFilter, ClientResponseFilter) are executed in the reverse order (using descending manner)](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e10067)

Comment: You are right. I didn't read the fine print there.  What is the reasoning for the reverse order for responses?

Comment: You know how when using servlet filters, the order of the inbound is opposite of the outbound, I think these filters are implemented similarly (as with most other types of filters).

Answer (score 0):

As [Paul Samsotha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68043020/jersey-client-error-unable-to-parse-invalid-content-type-header-need-workarou?noredirect=1#comment120268800_68043020) pointed out, I can fix this with a [ClientResponseFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientResponseFilter.html) using high priority. Here is one way one could do it.

```
import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.selinc.winchester.common.narrative.INarrative;
import com.selinc.winchester.sentinel.Sentinel;
import com.selinc.winchester.wrestler.ResponsePriorities;

@Provider
@Priority(25000) // Note the priority ordering is reverse of ClientRequestFilter
public final class ResponseHeaderWorkaroundFilter implements ClientResponseFilter
{
  @Override
  public void filter(final ClientRequestContext requestContext, final ClientResponseContext responseContext)
  {
    try
    {
      // Attempt to read the Content-Type header.
      responseContext.getMediaType();
    }
    catch (Throwable error)
    {
      // On error, set the Content-Type header to some default value.
      responseContext.getHeaders()
        .putSingle(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }
  }
}
```